# JSF validation on Hibernate column

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I create a column with Hibernate with the default size of 255 e.g.:

```
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
```

And in my view: 
    `<h:inputText value="#{userController.user.name}" />`

Will JSF validate for the max 255 chars of the database column on user input for `name` by default? 
If not, what is the best practice, do I have to define the max size of `name` with `length` attribute or use `f:validateLength`?

Comment: If you use bean validation in entities themselves (for example, Hibernate Validator - a reference implementation of bean validation), then it will do. You can also use JSF validators. Use either of them but what problem did you experience with `<f:validateLength>`? Did it not work for some reason?

Comment: This is more like a general question..What is the best practice? Does JSF validate the default column size created in general? Maybe I should delete it anyway...

Comment: JSF will not validate unless an appropriate validator is used as obvious. Bean validation (JSR-349, formerly JSR-303) will not be triggered unless it is properly configured (in case of Servlet containers) and an appropriate annotation(s) is used in the target bean / entity.